# When a site moves into public beta, are its questions immediately eligible for HNQ?

Tags: support, beta-phase, hot-questions

When a site moves into public beta, are its questions immediately eligible to appear on the Hot Network Questions?  Or does the SE staff still have to activate something in order for that to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The questions are immediately eligible.

Comment: OK, I just wasn't sure why a question such as [this](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22259/different-usage-of-bin-gegangen) with only 1 upvote is on HNQ, but [this question](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/390/why-did-elvis-presley-never-tour-overseas) with 8 upvotes isn't.

Comment: Time is a big factor. It is entirely possible that both have been featured at different times.

Comment: This was probably the first HNQ for Music Fans: http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/447/when-did-the-standard-drumkit-become-popular-in-music